# VSCode how do I stay on source control tab?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've started having an odd issue.

**Previous behavior (what I want):**

When I go to the source control tab and click a file then the comparison window opens to the right, and I would remain on the source control tab.
The explorer tab will move to the file if I'm on the explorer tab.

**Current behavior:**
When I open the change comparison, it is now jumping out of the source control tab and to the file in the explorer window.

**The main behavior difference is**

I do not want to change feature tabs automatically (source control vs explorer etc). The use case is I want to be able to quickly go down the list of diffs and see them all without having to switch back to the source control tab when viewing each file. I do want the explorer to track which file is open so that if I'm on the explorer tab I am viewing the file in the correct directory.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  You may have to run the `BIsect` command or the `Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command to see if some extension is interfering.  You could also try setting `Explorer: Auto Reveal` to false.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning BIsect. I had no idea that was there. It took two run throughs (maybe the first had loading issues?) but it discovered an extension that was causing the issue.